# Display prompt based on when condition

Tags: ansible

I want to prompt a certain question after a certain value is given to another prompt in Ansible, but I'm not being able to do that.

I want domain decision to appear after answering option `1`, it should not ask for domain decision if the answer is different than `1`.

Code:

```yaml
- name: os_system
  private: no
  prompt: |
  Which os do you want to use?
   1- Windows Server
   2- CentOS_7
   3- CentOs_8
   4- Ubuntu
   5- Others
- name: Domain Decision
  private: no
  prompt: Do you want your PC in Domain
  when: (os_system == "1" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `when` statement in `vars_prompt`, [as answered in their issue tracker](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19777).

This said, you can use `pause` that also lets you `prompt` for variables and use them via the [`user_input`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html#return-user_input) return value.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no    
        
  tasks:
    - name: OS System
      pause:
        prompt: |
          Which OS do you want to use?
          1- Windows Server
          2- CentOS 7
          3- CentOS 8
          4- Ubuntu
          5- Others
      register: os_system
    - name: Domain Decision
      pause:
        prompt: In which domain do you want your PC?
      when: os_system.user_input == "1"
```

Here are two run of it:

- When answering `2`

  ```
  PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

  TASK [OS System] ***************************************************************
  [os_system]
  Which OS do you want to use?
  1- Windows Server
  2- CentOS 7
  3- CentOS 8
  4- Ubuntu
  5- Others
  :
  ok: [localhost] 

  TASK [Domain Decision] *********************************************************
  skipping: [localhost]

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- When answering `1`

  ```
  PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

  TASK [OS System] ***************************************************************
  [os_system]
  Which OS do you want to use?
  1- Windows Server
  2- CentOS 7
  3- CentOS 8
  4- Ubuntu
  5- Others
  :
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [Domain Decision] *********************************************************
  [Domain Decision]
  In which domain do you want your PC?:
  ok: [localhost]

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```